# flutter column and row intersection table

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

Hello, I'm currently working on a new app but I'm stuck somewhere. I want to make a table with intersecting rows and columns in flutter. There is an example in the picture, can you help me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`DataTable`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html) widget.

Below is an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DataTable(
      columns: const <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Name',
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Age',
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Role',
              style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      rows: const <DataRow>[
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
            DataCell(Text('19')),
            DataCell(Text('Student')),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Janine')),
            DataCell(Text('43')),
            DataCell(Text('Professor')),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('William')),
            DataCell(Text('27')),
            DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```